# Nucleophilic Aromatic substitution in 3-Bromoanisole

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, nucleophilic-substitution

I came across an example in my textbook where $\ce{3-Bromoanisole}$ is reacted with $\ce{NaNH2}$ in liq. $\ce{NH3}$. My understanding is that the reaction would proceed by a Benzyne intermediate, with the triple bond between $\ce{C2}$ and $\ce{C3}$. Now, I know that the carbanion must be formed where it is most stable. Since $\ce{C3}$ is at meta position with respect to the $\ce{-OCH3}$ group, the electron density there must be lower, and hence that is where the carbanion should be formed, leaving us with the $\ce{-NH2}$ group at $\ce{C3}$, forming a product that will be more stable due to hydrogen bonding between the $\ce{-OCH3}$ and $\ce{-NH2}$ groups. However, in my textbook it says that a meta-substituted product is formed with no explanation. To me, it seems like that would be very unstable as the $\ce{-OCH3}$ group would be increasing the electron density by both resonance and the inductive effect. Can someone please explain what I'm missing?

Comment: The methoxy group is electron-withdrawing by induction, so the nucleophile will attack C3 to place the carbanion as close as possible to the methoxy group.